# set default value for custom field type: list_boolean / options_onoff

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

```
$instance = array(
      'field_name' => $field_name,
      'entity_type' => $entity,
      'bundle' => $bundle,
      'field types' => 'list_boolean',
      'widget' => array(
            'type' => 'options_onoff',
            'settings' => array('display_label' => 1)
        ),
      'default_value' => array(array('value' => 1)),
    );
```

this is not taken, and i have to save it twice in the admin contenttype - field/edit,
until it takes it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i now exported the finished field with the [features module](http://drupal.org/project/features),
and took the generated code - suddenly it works, with `default_value`

i guess i was missing the property `module` on the field, also `field types` is inexistant ..

Answer (score 1):

In your field definition, you have to set the allowed_values in the settings array in order for the default_value in the instance to get picked up.

so like this assuming you are doing this in a module

```
$fields[] = array(
  'field_name' => '$field_name',
  'type' => 'list_boolean',
  'settings' => array(
    'allowed_values' => drupal_map_assoc(range(0, 1)),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'default_value', I got it to work by using 'default_value_function' and creating a function that returns array(array('value' => 1)).

Comment: i cant get it work - with d7.9 and d7.10 ..., creating the field in module.install while installing or enabling the module, the function laying in the module.install file too. i also found this issue http://drupal.org/node/1342984 **scary**

Comment: I put the default_value_function in the .module file not the .install file.